# Compare how long two functions took

Tags: c

I have two functions and I want to print how long each of them took to finish.

What I have so far:

```
int main()
{
   clock_t tic1 = clock();
   shell_sort(array, 100000);
   clock_t toc1 = clock();
   printf("shellsort took: %f seconds\n", (double)(toc1 - tic1) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

   clock_t tic2 = clock();
   bubble_sort(array, 100000);
   clock_t toc2 = clock();
   printf("bubblesort took: %f seconds\n", (double)(toc2 - tic2) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

   return 0;
}
```

It should work fine, but after printing duration of first function it stops. It feels like the program is still running. There is no "Press any key to continue". How can I fix this?

Comment: Who is supposed to print "Press any key to continue" ?

Comment: @koper I guess you are using the shell sort you used in earlier question, you know why bubble sort s taking time to sort 100,000 values. just wait.

Comment: The problem can be undefined behavior, it depends on your implementation of the functions.

Comment: Or start with 1000 values, and then increase to 3000, then 10000, 30000, and finally 100000 (if you have the patience for that).

Comment: Thank you guys. I just waited few minutes and it printed results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume your sort functions are fine.

You are trying to check the time it takes bubble sort to sort 100,000 values. I guess you know its quite slow. Have patience and [wait](https://vinayakgarg.wordpress.com/2011/10/25/time-comparison-of-quick-sort-insertion-sort-and-bubble-sort/).

[image]

As you can see for a hundred thousand entries you should wait almost a minute.